# What do we call the stream-like leftovers of water sticking to a glass surface?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, translation

From a Russian document:

> Лабораторная посуда считается чистой, если вода, стекающая по стенкам, не оставляет капель или «**ручейков**».

Translation:

> Laboratory glassware is considered clean when the water running down its walls doesn't leave drops or "**rivulets**".

But I'm not sure about "rivulets". What is meant in the original text are elongated, thread-like drops that would make the laboratory beaker hard to use, because these drops will make measurements imprecise.

I wonder what the natural-sounding English term would be for these.

From a [website](http://www.titrations.info/glass-cleaning) dedicated to titrations:

> Laboratory glassware have to be perfectly clean before it can be used for any type of analytical work. There are two reasons for that. If the glass is not perfectly clean, water will not wet its surface, and it will be present on the glass surface in the form of droplets. It is impossible to account for volume of these droplets, so you will never know what volume of the reagent was used - and as the precision of the volume measurements is the basis of the precision of the volumetric methods, dirty volumetric glass means huge errors.

> [image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that *rivulets* is fine. Look at these examples:

> Blue drops of rain trickles in rivulets on a black background. — [Dreamstime Stock Video](https://www.dreamstime.com/stock-video-footage-beautiful-background-blue-drops-rain-trickles-rivulets-black-background-paint-falling-down-glass-video85589303)

> Sun Tuff roofing with rain drops and rivulets — [Alamy Stock Photo](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-sun-tuff-roofing-with-rain-drops-and-rivulets-17446729.html?pv=1&stamp=2&imageid=3CDB5ED7-6416-4489-A5D9-B0405CF5845E&p=3381&n=0&orientation=0&pn=1&searchtype=0&IsFromSearch=1&srch=foo%3Dbar%26st%3D0%26pn%3D1%26ps%3D100%26sortby%3D2%26resultview%3DsortbyPopular%26npgs%3D0%26qt%3Drivulets%26qt_raw%3Drivulets%26lic%3D3%26mr%3D0%26pr%3D0%26ot%3D0%26creative%3D%26ag%3D0%26hc%3D0%26pc%3D%26blackwhite%3D%26cutout%3D%26tbar%3D1%26et%3D0x000000000000000000000%26vp%3D0%26loc%3D0%26imgt%3D0%26dtfr%3D%26dtto%3D%26size%3D0xFF%26archive%3D1%26groupid%3D%26pseudoid%3D%26a%3D%26cdid%3D%26cdsrt%3D%26name%3D%26qn%3D%26apalib%3D%26apalic%3D%26lightbox%3D%26gname%3D%26gtype%3D%26xstx%3D0%26simid%3D%26saveQry%3D%26editorial%3D1%26nu%3D%26t%3D%26edoptin%3D%26customgeoip%3D%26cap%3D1%26cbstore%3D1%26vd%3D0%26lb%3D%26fi%3D2%26edrf%3D0%26ispremium%3D1%26flip%3D0%26pl%3D)

> Soap suds and rivulets of water on window glass of a red saloon car being washed in an automated car — [Alamy Stock Photo](https://www.alamy.com/soap-suds-and-rivulets-of-water-on-window-glass-of-a-red-saloon-car-being-washed-in-an-automated-car-wash-image347006182.html)

Alternatively, these can be called *trails*:

> Vertical shot of a window with water trails and a blurred background — [Stock Editorial Photography](https://depositphotos.com/301573368/stock-photo-vertical-shot-of-a-window.html)

Comment: I actually think of rivulets as containing flowing water, not streaks or drops of stationary water clinging to a surface.

Comment: For what it's worth, "rivulets" was the word I thought of before reading past the title.

Answer (score 11):

**The word is droplet**

There is nothing wrong with using "droplets" as in the website you reference. A rivulet is a thin stream of water that is flowing. A droplet is a small drop that adheres to the surface.

[Look at some of these images](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=droplets&atb=v245-1&iax=images&ia=images)

Answer (score 8):

I'd call it a streak.

> **streak** [noun]
>
> a long, narrow mark, smear, band of color, or the like:
>
> - *streaks of mud.*

[[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/streak)]

- *If your wipers are leaving streaks of water on the windshield* ... ([Advert on Google](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fsites.google.com%2Fa%2Fk.emumo.info%2Fsites%2Fsystem%2Ferrors%2FSiteDisabled%3FdisabledSite%3Dk.emumo.info%2Fa959&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fsites.google.com%2Fa%2Fk.emumo.info%2Fsites%2Fsystem%2Ferrors%2FSiteDisabled%3FdisabledSite%3Dk.emumo.info%2Fa959&hd=k.emumo.info&service=jotspot&sacu=1&rip=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin)]

> **streak** [verb]
>
> to be in streaks.
>
> - *Rain streaked down the window.*

[[Kids.Wordsmyth](https://kids.wordsmyth.net/we/?level=2&rid=40769)]

Comment: In the noun form, many (most?) people would understand "streak" in this context to be dry dirty spots left in the path of water after it evaporated.  (Because there was some dirt for the water to spread around, or the water itself was dirty).  The votes on [comments under the question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/562009/what-do-we-call-the-stream-like-leftovers-of-water-sticking-to-a-glass-surface#comment1388967_562009) reflect this.

Answer (score 5):

With a wine **glass**, it may be called '**legs**'

The 'legs' of wine are the **droplets** that form along the edge of your glass, when you swirl a wine. Some believe that the appearance of them reflects the quality of the wine in the glass.

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=wine+tasting+legs+on+glass

Comment: Students don't waste wine washing out burettes.

Comment: Huh, I thought for wine it was called "tears": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marangoni_effect#Tears_of_wine. Other terms seem to include: wine legs, fingers, curtains, church windows, or feet. I don't think the thought of feet in my wine glass is very appetizing though...

Comment: @rubenvb. May have to keep feet out of it - or visit the vineyard! Now what's that word for walking around to crush the grapes with the feet....?

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a single word for a liquid version of a dingleberry.

You need describe the water as being stuck to the glass. Formally, the droplets are **adhered** to the glass. *Adhered* works as an adjective - ... the adhered droplets ...
Less formally, the droplets **cling** to the glass.

I prefer *adhered* in the passive construction because we understand from context that it is the cruddy glass that is more clingy than clean glass, and not that the droplets are more clingy than normal droplets.

Comment: Do you mean the third definition of [dingleberry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dingleberry)?

Comment: @IconDaemon I'm pretty sure, despite Merriam Webster's best efforts, that that's actually the *first* definition of dingleberry.

Comment: ... M-W is a 'historic dictionary' (like OED but not Lexico and many others): it lists polysemes in the order of appearance in the language, not current degree of idiomaticity.